# Is this the right and fastest query?

Tags: mysql

I need the optimal SQL query in the following job.
I have these tables:

```
host: idhost
table:  idtable, idhost
reservation: idtable, start, stop
```

And I need those hosts which has any free table at a period (2014-03-03 12:00 - 2014-03-03 14:00).

I use this query (i'm sure this gives back right result)

```
SELECT idhost FROM idhost WHERE idhost NOT IN (
    SELECT idhost FROM host INNER JOIN table USING (idhost) INNER JOIN reservation USING (idtable)
        WHERE :start BETWEEN start AND stop OR :stop BETWEEN start AND stop OR :start < start AND stop > :stop)
```

But somebody said the following query is faster and gives back the same host, but I'm not sure:

```
SELECT * FROM host  
    JOIN table USING (idhost)  
        LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.idtable = table.idtable AND  
             :start >= reservation.start AND :stop <= reservation.stop  
WHERE reservation.idtable IS NULL
```

Is it correct and faster? Or is there a better query?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try yourself rather than asking

Comment: In addition: try `EXPLAIN` syntax

Comment: Take a look at the "EXPLAIN" statement if you really need in-depth info about how your query runs. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/explain.html

Comment: The query looks like it should return the same data, and using joins instead of subqueries will almost always be faster, however your best bet is to try it and see.  On your dataset, things may change.

Comment: May need more memory though, @Jericon

Comment: 2nd query will be faster

Comment: OK, thanks! I just wasn't sure about this part: "...LEFT JOIN reservation ON reservation.idtable = table.idtable AND  
             :start >= reservation.start AND :stop <= reservation.stop..." and now I can't test it. So is this the optimal query?

Comment: Another vote for the 2nd query, although they do not give the same results (first gives the host with space, the 2nd gives the host and table with space)